# How to add a sound on click to a reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a Realtime Chat Application on ReactJs and I just need to add a sound whenever there's an incoming message. Can somebody help me out? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please edit. What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your problem that you don't know how to play audio with Javascript?

If so, all you need is to import the file and create an audio object like this 
`const audio = new Audio(importedFile);`.
Now any time you add a new message just do this `audio.play()`.

Note: The audio file should be inside src so that you can import it.

Look to my example for a better understanding.
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hermann-3fmpr?file=/src/App.js